# Yii2 set attribute value of all models in an array of models

Tags: php, arrays, yii2, attributes

Is there a way in yii2 to set one specific attribute value in all models in an array of models (of the same class)? I have searched but unfortunately found nothing relevant. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you tried to use foreach?

Comment: Nope... but you are basically right. I was just hoping that maybe there is something like `Arrayhelper::setValues`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Model::loadMultiple( $models, $data, $formName = null );`

This is an example of how you can do that:

```
$numberOfModelsInArray = sizeof($myDataArray);
$myModels = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfModelsInArray; $i++) {
     $myModels[] = new myModelForm();
}

VariantsForm::loadMultiple($myModels, $myDataArray, '');
```

To know more about loadMultiple() you can check https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#loadMultiple()-detail
for the documentation

Comment: I'm already doing `loadMultiple` and after that I would like to update a certain attribute in all models

Comment: Can u add your code to the question above. This will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a classical foreach loop you can also use `array_walk`:

```
\array_walk($carArray, function(&$car) { $car->engine = 'electric'; });
```

Another way would be to use `Model::loadMultiple` with a repeated array:

```
Model::loadMultiple(
    $carArray,
    \array_fill(0, count($carArray), ['engine' => 'electric']),
    ''
);
```

The last parameter is an empty string to make Yii expect the exact structure of the second parameter.

---

*Outdated after clarification:*

There is a static method on `ActiveRecord` called [`updateAll`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#updateAll()-detail):

```
Car::updateAll(['engine' => 'electric'], ['manufacturer' => 'Tesla']);
// UPDATE car SET engine = 'electric' WHERE 'manufacturer' = 'Tesla'
```

This will set the `engine` attribute of all cars manufactured by Tesla to `'electric'`. If you do not specify the condition in the second argument, all cars will get updated.

If you absolutely need to do this for a processed array, you could map the primary key values and pass those as a value instead. Your condition will then be turned into a `WHERE id IN(...)`.

```
$carArray = [$car1, $car2, $car3];
$carArrayIds = \array_map(function ($car) {
    return $car->id;
}, $carArray);

Car::updateAll(['engine' => 'electric'], ['id' => $carArrayIds]);
// UPDATE car SET engine = 'electric' WHERE 'id' IN (1, 2, 3)
```

And, last but not least, if none of this is possible, try updating all the models in a single database transaction.

```
$transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
try {
    foreach ($carArray as $car) {
        $car->engine = 'electric';
        if ($car->update() !== 1) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Single car update failed');
        }
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollback();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but the models should be already saved for that. That's the point that I would like to do it before save.

Comment: You can do it with `Model::loadMultiple`, mrateb's answer makes more sense.

Comment: @user2511599 Added the right way to do it using `Model::loadMultiple`.